# How to Forward Cookies in NextJs 14 Server Component Fetach API

Tags: next.js, cookies

I have Nextjs 14 App router app. Client components are forwarding the cookie properly during fetch API requests. However, server components are NOT. The cookie is created by my Java backend API with samesite LAX, httpOnly, secure properties. NextJS runs on [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) and the API runs on api.domain.com. Please help!!! Here's what I tried:

```
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

const getData = async (url: string): Promise => {
const response = await fetch(url, {
method: "POST",
headers: { Cookie: cookies().toString() },
});
const SummaryCard = async () => {
const { a, b } = await getData(
${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL}/api/accounts
);
return(

)
}
```